# Service -desktop Communication

Tags: powershell, service, interactive

I have WCF Service hosted on windows. The WCF service actually invokes a Powershell script which in turn has commands to run a third party EXE. This powershell script also communicates with the exe by setting it to focus and  sending key strokes. My problem is everything goes according to plan except that script is unable to send key strokes as windows service runs in different session (session 0) , hence my service is unable to communicate to the desktop (user's current session). Can anybody help me in making a communication between service and desktop.